# manually approach to check vulnerabilities?

Tags: vulnerability

How to check for different vulnerabilities mainly XSS, SQL Injection, CSRF manually???

We are not supposed to use any interceptor tool to read request and all.

Is there any other way by which we can intercept any request without any tool or plugin??

Comment: Yes you can check for vulnerabilities manually.  There are entire books dedicated to doing just this.  That said, an answer to this question would be far to large to place here.  I like "The Web Application Hacker's Handbook", but there are many others.

Comment: Also - you want to intercept requests without ANY tool?  How would you like to capture them?

Comment: "We are not supposed to use..." Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use an interceptor (and I suppose the task is some sort of exercise) you will usually not need one.

You can try to insert some attacks manually in a form or whatever you have. Checking for possible XSS attacks is possible if you send a custom string `ABCDEFG` and look where it appears in the resulting page. You can then try to refine that string and insert some tags, e.g.

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

If that raises a message you have successfully injected code.

You can try to start an SQLi by inserting SQL queries in a form element. I would start by adding `'` an see if that results in an SQL error message somewhere on the resulting page. Often useful is also to replace number by equations. E.g. `10` by `11-1`. If that validates you know that your input is directly passed to the SQL engine. You can then try to inject some more sophisticated queries. I recommend the cheat sheet from pentestmonkey which you can find here http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/mysql-sql-injection-cheat-sheet

For CSRF you have to have a *foreign* page which includes an element that, when loaded, results in a query to the site you want to attack. For example

```
<img src="http://some.site/user.php?deleteme">
```

which would make the browser request that site and possibly execute a deletion of a user account or so.

The web is full of further information and cheat sheets with common attack patterns. Just google it ;-)